# Strangely empty DataFrame after groupby and agg

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

With pandas I want to do something very similar to

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {((('Message1',),('Message1','Message4',)),('Message4',)): 10}
dict2 = {(1677, 468): 3}
dict3 = {(1677, 468): 1, (2078, 869): 1 }

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1, orient='index'). \
    reset_index(). \
    rename(columns={'index': 'pair', 0: 'pair_count'})

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2, orient='index'). \
    reset_index(). \
    rename(columns={'index': 'pair', 0: 'pair_count'})

df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict3, orient='index'). \
    reset_index(). \
    rename(columns={'index': 'pair', 0: 'pair_count'})

pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).\
    groupby('pair').\
    sum()
```

If you run the code above, this should work. However with my data, which looks very similar, but longer in regards of dict2 and dict3, this does not work. I am able to concatenate the DataFrames, but then when I do the grouping and the sum, I receive an empty DataFrame.

Unfortunately, when I try to reproduce the error by extracting the data, this does work. (This is why I am not able to post an example where the error occurs.) So I guess this issue is not about the data itself... maybe, because here is the weirdest thing: If I change dict1 to

```
dict1 = {((('Message1',),('Message1',)),('Message4',)): 10}
```

I get the desired result.

Comment: is there a special meaning to the nesting of the tuples in `dict1`

Comment: @MaartenFabré: If you mean whether I can unnest them: No I can't. `('Message1',)` might be the same as `'Message1'`, but I think my program produces the nested tuples as seen in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so much that the pair's aren't hashable (they are), 
because if that was the case, `df1` would give an error during creation

It's the fact pandas `groupby` sorts, and Python can't sort `int` vs `tuple` vs `str`, so changing the `groupby` to `groupby('pair', sort=False)` should do the trick

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).\
    groupby('pair', sort=False).\
    sum()
```

@Allen's answer changes the `tuple` to `string`, circumventing the root cause

Comment: What is the sort good for? Only to have the groups sorted after the aggregation? Why is this the default, I basically never need this?

Comment: I don't know why the sorting is default [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-sorting) is what the documentation has to say about it

Comment: Good to know the root cause. Thanks @MaartenFabré

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because your group key is not hashable. Try to convert it to string type to see how it goes.

```
df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
df4.groupby(df4.pair.astype(str)).sum()
Out[251]: 
                                                    pair_count
pair                                                          
((('Message1',), ('Message1', 'Message4')), ('M...          10
(1677, 468)                                                  4
(2078, 869)
```

Comment: I added `df4.pair = df4.pair.astype(str)` after the concatenation. That helped: +1

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution messed my program up later... :-/, while Maarten Farbré's solution worked all the way through. I still appreciate your solution though and will keep the +1.

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding a `.copy()` was the simple fix:

```py
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).\
copy().\
groupby('pair').\
sum()
```

Comment: Interesting. Why would that work...?

Comment: No idea, the other solutions didn't work and I started trying stuff until this worked